# IE8 Body not taking 100% height

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, height, document-body

In my application I am having problem to cover completely a page of the browser window in IE8.

The HTML:

```
<body class="body">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-holder">
            <form id="Form1" runat="server">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
.body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#2F2727), color-stop(0.25, #1a82f7), color-stop(0.5, #2F2727), color-stop(0.75, #1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    height: 100%;
}
.main-holder {
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#F8AC25), color-stop(0.05, #FFF999), color-stop(0.5, #F8AC25), color-stop(0.95, #FFF999), to(#F8AC25));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #F8AC25, #FFF999 5%, #F8AC25, #FFF999 95%, #F8AC25);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial Sans-Serif;
}
```

But in IE8 there are two white strips on top and bottom of the page. And for that reason the body is not covering the page completely, but in Firefox it does.

Screenshot IE8:

[image]

Screenshot Firefox:

[image]

In IE8 their is an offset around wrapper:

[image]

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken IE needs the 100% to be applied to `<html>` and `<body>` tags for this to work.

Comment: @Andreas Hagen Thanks. Are you saying that I should add html body{height: 100%;} ?

Comment: Remember the comma :) `html, body {height: 100%;}`

Comment: @Andreas Hagen thanks. I did this as you said, then the bottom strip gone, but there is still a strip on top. I have added another picture that says there is an offset 10 set to the `wrapper`.

Comment: That is probably the margin from html or body. I will post it in an answer instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the html or body element. Try this:

```
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

Be aware that setting height to 100% will probably give you problems when the site flows out of the canvas so the scrollbars appear. The height will then still be 100% and probably cause issues with the overflowed content.

Comment: I have set html, body { height:100%; font-family: Arial Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Yea I see one more that might cause it: .main-holder pushes with `margin: 10px` which might push on body as well, use `padding: 10px 0` in body to achieve the effect instead

Comment: Thanks it works. But as you mentioned that their might be issues with the overflowed content, it happened, when I resize the browser. I have added another picture. Is there any turn around way? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `overflow: scroll` might save you if you are lucky, but you should generally avoid setting static heights like that. If you are not concerned about backward compatibility I suggest you use `min-height` for body to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the solution is: html, body {height:100%;} body{min-height: 810px;/* Since the min height of main-holder is 800px + 10px*/}. It worked. :)

Comment: setting min-height doesn't solve the problem of overflow. I used javascript to solve this. $(document).ready(function () {            
            setInterval(adjustBodyHeight, 100);
        }); var adjustBodyHeight = function () {
    var wrapperHeight = $('.wrapper').height();
    $('.body').height(wrapperHeight + 10 + "px");
}

Answer (score 2):

Your height of 100% needs to be applied to both the HTML and BODY tags:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

[Here's some more information!](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/comment-page-5/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. After using this the bottom strip has gone, but there is still a top strip.  You can see in the last picture there is an offset 10 set to the `wrapper`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
body
{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```